# how is data stored in dynamo db if hash and range key are same in global secondary index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am creating global secondary index in dynamo db, now I want to know how are items stored in of both hash key and range key are same? In what order they will be stored in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you are asking about two different objects, each with a unique primary key in the main table, that are projected into a GSI with the same HASH/RANGE key in the GSI.

*Example*

**Main table**

- Hash: hash_id
- Range: range_id

**GSI**

- Hash: gsi_hash_id
- Range: gsi_range_id

**Data**

```
{
  hash_id: 123,
  range_id: 'abc',
  gsi_hash_id: 'same',
  gsi_range_id: 'also_same'
}

{
  hash_id: 234,
  range_id: 'bcd',
  gsi_hash_id: 'same',
  gsi_range_id: 'also_same'
}
```

The short answer: the items are in no particular order.

The long answer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: so what happens if a new items get added to gsi will they be inserted on top, bottom or anywhere

Comment: No particular order means it could be inserted anywhere. Keep in mind, these documents are equivalent in terms of order. If you are looking for a solution to a particular problem, I'd suggest describing your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey), the hash and range/sort key together determine where the items are stored.

> All items with the same partition key value are stored together, in sorted order by sort key value.

This means that if you have two items with the same values, they will be stored physically close together based on the sort key order.